# Looking for a dataset or idea how to make it

Tags: database

I want to create a system where i can filter employees based on their programming skills let's say for example i need a java developer and employee 1 is 8/10 in java and employee 2 is 5/10 in C# and we say that java is 80 procent similar to C# then we need to return both employees where employee one has a score of 8 and employee 2 has a score of 4. Does something like this exist? Or does anybody have a clue how to get started on this?

i tried to use memgraph but i have no clue how to use it for something like this where calculations need to be perfomed on relations